# Facebook is still directing people to facebook.stackoverflow.com

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The [official Facebook Developers group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers) is still directing users to facebook.stackoverflow.com for technical issues.

Quoting from the groups "about" section:

> This is *not* a forum for asking detailed technical questions, use http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/ for that.

That mini-site/tag-filtered-site no longer exists and simply [redirects to a wildcard tag search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook*) - should this link still be distributed by Facebook? I think not.

Perhaps the SE team could request a change so that the section reads something on the lines of:

> Please use the various Facebook tags on Stack Overflow for asking detailed technical questions.

Comment: Also, it would be reasonable to redirect the link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook.

Comment: @AndersonGreen ^that's what currently does happen (you might be aware, I can't tell)

Comment: @OGHaza Then the redirect should change to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook?sort=votes, which lists the most frequently-asked questions instead of the newest questions.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Use the [frequent tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook?sort=frequent) for the most frequently asked, rather than the votes tab.

Comment: @AndersonGreen I suggest only a slight modification of the current redirection: stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook*?sort=frequent (it works in Chrome, but I can't get it to work in this comment) which still includes the multiple Facebook tags.

Answer (score 1):

(Upped my comment to an answer because it seems to have been implemented.)

I suggest only a slight modification of the current redirection:

stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook*

which includes the multiple Facebook tags.

Comment: They're still implying this is a forum...