# Word wrap not right on Windows Phone

Tags: bug, windows-phone

I don't know if you care yet (or at all) but sometimes the word wrapping or simply the right column is wrong in Internet Explorer on a Windows Phone:

[image: screen grab showing text cut off]

Note the RHS of the displayed text is not the RHS of the display.

[image: screen grab showing some correct wrapping]

This is further up in the [same question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225309/147650).

This problem appears on a number of SE sites.

I should mention the best solution I've noticed so far is to rotate my phone and look at the landscape ratio. (And there are differing results as you zoom in and out, but this is the default scenario it returns to eventually.) Note also it really has the wrong idea of my screen width, which is why I have been able to shift the display left before taking these screen grabs - i.e. there's no problem on the LHS, I've just been able to "scroll right" to highlight I cannot see the RHS text.

(I added this question on my phone without the help of the toolbar and no preview. I've since edited it from a computer.)